# Using associations in hooks with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm in a hard situation with FactoryGirl that maybe you can help me to solve. The code is like this:

```
class Bet
  belongs_to :market
  belongs_to :option
  has_one :market, :through => :option
  has_one :event, :through => :market   

  before_validation :set_event_date

  scope :by_event_date, order(arel_table[:event_date].desc) 

  def set_event_date
    self.event_date = event.date
  end
end
```

I need to materialize the event_date attribute in Bet because the scope `by_event_date` is too costly without the materialization. The problem comes when I run `FactoryGirl.create :bet`. The hook gets executed, but `bet.event` is nil, and therefore an exception raises. Is there anyway to configure FactoryGirl to really create the associated objects?

Answer (score 1):

what's your factory code? you can do something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    #something
  end

  factory :bet do
    #something
    event
  end
end
```

that should create an event for you

you can also use factorygirl callbacks to customize it a little

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    #something
  end

  factory :bet do
    #something
    after_build do |bet| #for newer version it is after(:build) do |bet|...
      bet.event = Factory.build(:event)
    end
  end
end
```

when the record is saved the event will be saved to

EDIT: try assigning a market then

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    #something
  end

  factory :market do
    event
  end

  factory :bet do
    #something
    market
  end
end
```

Comment: None works. In the first example, can't access directly to the event from the factory because it is a through association. In the second, after(:build) is executed after the object before_validation.

Comment: I already have this done and it doesn't work either. :P The only way I found to make it work is to follow the full "path" in the `set_event_date` method: `self.event_date = option.market.event.date`. But it's extremely ugly.